# Writing blob file into database by using the sql statement insert into

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I am searching at the moment for a possibility in Advantage Database Server via sql to put a byte stream, so called blob file into a table. When I build up a complete database I am doing it like this:

```
TBlobField(BaseTable.FieldByName('BlobData')).LoadFromStream(BinaryStream);
```

Now I would like to add an Entry into my database where one Field has the 'BlobData'.
I started like that:

```
FADSQuery.SQL.Add('Insert Into '+DBName'+'(BlobData)');
TBlobField(FADSQuery.ParamByName('BlobData')).LoadFromStream(BinaryStream);
```

But the compiler tells me it cannot find the `BlobData` field.:(
Is it nearly right to do it like that? I wouldn't like to put inside the insert into statement a whole file by filename.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "advanced database server" or "Advantage Database Server" ?

Comment: `"But the compiler tells me it cannot find the BlobData"`. Please don't "translate" error messages for us. Always provide the *exact* error message you're receiving. Even if the error message doesn't tell *you* much, it might tell allot to someone else.

Comment: So, it is the Advantage Database Server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
FADSQuery.SQL.Add('Insert Into '+DBName+'(BlobData) values (:BlobData)');
FADSQuery.ParamByName('BlobData').LoadFromStream(BinaryStream, ftBlob);
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a syntax for the named parameter and for spotting the wrongly cast to `TBlobField`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that fast answer. It helped me a lot. And works by including the blobtype : FADSQuery.ParamByName('BlobData').LoadFromStream(BinaryStream,ftBlob);

Comment: @AndréDziurla: if it solves the problem, would be nice to mark this answer as "Accepted".

Comment: +1. I'd suggest just using `FADSQuery.SQL.Text` instead, though, since the `INSERT` is probably the only statement and you won't have to worry about clearing the previous SQL first.